# Designing a scalable backend system that triggers events based on time values

Tags: architecture, backend, system-design, event-driven-design, scalable

I am trying to understand a system design where events are triggered based on certain time or expiration of a time values and these time values can be in the millions. I was researching something else and I stumbled upon this problem and now I am unable to find a good scalable solution.

I couldnt find anything in stackoverflow either.

Any software architect who could point me in the right resources or ideas on how to approach this?
Please give specifics rather than say just event driven architecture.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) open source project that is used by multiple production systems to perform time-based triggering among other things. It scales to hundreds of millions of parallel periodic jobs.

Disclaimer: I'm a founder and tech lead of the project.